# How to mapping XML tag by matching the tag with a string using Python?

Tags: python, xml, string, tags, mapping

I have an XML file.

Here is the content:

```
<Country>
     <number no="2008" info="update">
          <detail name="man1" class="A1">
               <string name="ruth" />
               <string name="amy" />
          </detail>
          <detail name="man2" class="A2">
               <string name="lisa" />
               <string name="graham" />
          </detail>
     </number>
     <number no="2006" info="update">
          <detail name="woman1" class="B1">
               <string name="grace" />
               <string name="chil" />
          </detail>
          <detail name="woman2" class="B2">
               <string name="emy" />
               <string name="toms" />
          </detail>
     </number>
</Country>
```

I need to get the value of number in here `<number no="2008"` by mapping with this value `class="A1"`

I tried this way, but It print `None`.
here is the code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
ReadXML = ET.parse('data.xml')
stringno = 'A1'
for family in ReadXML.findall('./number/detail[@class="{}"]'.format(stringno)):
    name = family.get('no')
    print(name)
```

Anyone can help me, please. Thanks a lot

Comment: is this `xml.etree` or `lxml`? Does `ReadXML` has `xpath()` method?

Comment: @har07 I used  `xml.etree` like this  `ReadXML = ET.parse('data.xml')` 
No, I don't have `xpath` method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use XPath expression to select element `number` by `class` attribute of `detail` child, then you can read `no` attribute from selected `number` from python: `number[detail/@class="A1"]`

But `findall()` only supports [limited subset of XPath](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#elementtree-xpath) expression which doesn't include the XPath above. We need to resort to a simpler XPath expression, for example using your attempted XPath then selecting parent of matched `detail` elements using `..`:

```
stringno = 'A1'
for family in ReadXML.findall('number/detail[@class="{}"]/..'.format(stringno)):
    name = family.get('no')
    print(name)
```

Comment: yeah! It works. You're great! Thanks a lot.

Comment: hi @har07. I have a problem when the value of  `class="A1\X2"` something  like that. if you don't mind, could you please give any advice or idea. Thank you